# How can I use a regex to match a class or id in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, regex, drupal

I am using the code below to expand a fieldset in Drupal based on the fieldset's id. The problem is that the id can only be used on a single content type, making it necesssary to duplicate it on all content types with a metatags field group.

Can the code be adjusted to match on any fieldsets that match an id prefixed by `group_metatags_xxxxx`

```
(function ($){
  Drupal.behaviors.dynamicCollapsedFieldset = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      $('.page-node-add #group_metatags').once('dynamic-collapsed-fieldset').removeClass('collapsed');
    }
  }
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Try `$('.page-node-add [id^="group_metatags"]').once('dynamic-collapsed-fieldset').removeClass('collapsed');`

Comment: I tried your solution and it works. Is it a Javascript technique or is it specifically a jQuery method? Is there a pointer in the documentation to it?

Will you also make the comment an answer so I can award points to it? I suppose at 112400 points it is marginal ;). I guess should answer it myself and boost my meagre ranking :)

Comment: Added it as an answer with reference links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking at is [attribute starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) - it is a part of [css attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

So try

```
$('.page-node-add [id^="group_metatags"]').once('dynamic-collapsed-fieldset').removeClass('collaps‌​ed');
```

Comment: Thanks for the links to the documentation!!